# Watching Value Prop in Vue3 Composition API with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

As far as I can tell, what I'm doing is supposed to work correctly, based off of several examples I've found online, and a general pattern I believe I understood correctly from Wave UI's drawer source code.

Basically I have a sidebar component, and I want it to be hideable according to a value prop supplied to it (the idea being it can be changed according to whatever the parent component needs, screen size, toggle button, etc.). So the sidebar component has a watch function on it that is supposed to react to changes in props.value

Sidebar.vue

```js
<template>
  <aside v-if="mountSidebar" class="min-h-screen">
    <slot></slot>
  </aside>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, watch } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Sidebar",
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const mountSidebar = ref(props.value);

    watch(
      () => props.value,
      (value) => {
        mountSidebar.value = value;
      }
    );

    return {
      close,
      mountSidebar,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

And then the App.vue where the sidebar is currently displayed.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <navbar>
          <dm-button rounded type="primary" @click="showSidebar = !showSidebar">Toggle Sidebar</dm-button>
      Navbar Content
    </navbar>
    <div class="flex flex-row min-h-screen bg-gray-100 text-gray-800">
      <sidebar v-model="showSidebar">
        Sidebar Content
      </sidebar>
      <div class="flex justify-center w-full">
        <router-view />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar.vue";
import Sidebar from "@/components/Sidebar.vue";
import DmButton from "@/components/Button.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Sidebar,
    DmButton,
  },
  setup() {
    const showSidebar = ref(true);

    return {
      showSidebar,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

My App.vue has a `showSidebar` boolean ref, which is supplied as a `v-model` on the sidebar component. There is also a dm-button (an extended button component I wrote) that toggles the value of showSidebar on click (I know this works, I can see the `showSidebar` value changing in the App.vue component in the Vue Devtools). However, the change is not reflected in the sidebar component. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

FYI this code is simplified to have some unnecessary stuff removed (like the content inside the sidebar and navbars for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `v-model` with a component you should name the prop `modelValue` and emit an event called `update:modelValue` to mutate it :

```
<template>
  <aside v-if="modelValue" class="min-h-screen">
    <slot></slot>
  </aside>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, watch } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Sidebar",
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
emits:['update:modelValue'],
  setup(props,{emit}) {
  

      function close(){
         emit('update:modelValue',false)
      }

    return {
      close,
      mountSidebar,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: I guess I just didn't understand that the emit part was required for the child to listen for the v-model changes, I thought that was just so that the parent could listen for the emits and adjust its state accordingly if the child component also had ways to mutate its own state that parent needed to be aware of.

Is the name modelValue important or was that just for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

By creating a new ref from `props.value` you lost the reactivity.
`props` is a [`reactive`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#reactive), so you can use [`toRef`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#torefs) or [`toRefs`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#torefs).

```js
const mountSidebar = toRef(props, 'value');
// or
const {value:mountSidebar} = toRefs(props);
```

Comment: `mountSidebar` isn't meant to be reactive, it just gets its initial value from the props. Eventually there will be some logic so that when the v-model is updated a transition animation starts which will manually mutate mountSidebar and possibly another value that I haven't coded in yet. The solution by @BoussadjraBrahim solved my problem.